# Subscribe model: User to User relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a model `Subscribe`. Migration looks like this:

```
Schema::create('subscribes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('channel_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The defined relationships are:

```
class User
{
    public function subscribes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subscribe', 'channel_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Subscribe
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

How can I display all subscribed users for another user?

Comment: Your user has many subscriptions through the `channel_id` reference, but there is also a `user_id` reference. Can you explain what they stand for?

Comment: After subscribe a user, yout id will be save in `user_id`. Id of user which is subscribe by you is save in `channel_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you really want is two relationships on each model, one for subscriptions and one for followers. You can also add additional functions to retrieve subscriptions and followers:

```
class User
{
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscribe::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscribe::class, 'channel_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getFollowedUsers()
    {
        return User::query()
            ->whereHas('followers.subscribingUser', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', $this->id);
            })
            ->get();
    }

    public function getFollowingUsers()
    {
        return User::query()
            ->whereHas('subscriptions.followedUser', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', $this->id);
            })
            ->get();
    }
}

class Subscribe
{
    public function subscribingUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function followedUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'channel_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

*Note: I changed `subscribes` to `subscriptions` because that's the correct wording.*

With these relationships and methods, displaying both, subscribed and followed users, is extremely simple:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$subscriptions = $user->getFollowedUsers();
$followers     = $user->getFollowingUsers();
```

Comment: It works but I can't use posts relationship: `dd($user->posts)` - works,  `dd($followers->posts)` and `dd($subscriptions->posts)` doesn't works.

Comment: Definitely should. Are there really posts for these users? Is there an error or an empty collection?

Comment: Yes. Users has a posts. Error: `Property [posts] does not exist on this collection instance.`. In my opinion `$user` return one user while `$subscriptions` return a cellection of users.

Comment: Yes, sure. I used the plural because it's a collection of users, not a single one. You obviously can only access their posts in a loop like `foreach($followers as $user) { var_dump($user->posts); }`.

Comment: Yes, but I want to display all posts and sort it not by user just by date (`created_at`).

Comment: That is not what you asked for, but it is absolutely analogous to grabbing the users, just one hierarchy deeper: `public function getPostsOfFollowedUsers() { return Post::query()->whereHas('user.followers.subscribingUser', function ($query) { $query->where('id', $this->id); })->get(); }`